# Do I need to convert regular html code to follow codeigniter standard?

Tags: codeigniter

Since I ported my website to codeigniter I am wondering if I really need to convert regular html code to codeigniter coding standard.

Say for example I have the following html code:

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" size="32" maxlength="32" value="<?php echo $first_name ?>">
```

In codeigniter I can do the same as above or use the following code:

```
$format = 'size="32" maxlength="32"';

echo form_input('first_name', '$first_name', $format);
```

So which one should I follow?

Answer (score 2):

Just do this for ease:

```
echo '<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" size="32" maxlength="32" value="'.$first_name.'">';
```

its better and suggestable and also supported by each browser damn sure

Answer (score 0):

Leave your code as it is, there is no standard in writing HTML here, use whatever suits you best and whatever is more readable for you. Your way is much more rapid, than CodeIgniter's as it's basically plain html with echo of one variable. CodeIgniter's helper is basically an option for lazy ones to get things up faster, if you're familiar with them. 
If you work in a team and then ask for your designer or the one that's usually working with frontend and he's not familiar with CodeIgniter you will have to change things by yourself.